# pyodbc Binary Column is returning odd characters python

Tags: python, sql-server, binary, hex, pyodbc

I have a code that prints the query from db, I have no problems displaying values for Varchar, int and other format, But the value of Byteary is different. The value on the DB is something like `0xA09080BD1160AB16` but the result in print of python is like

```
b'\x03\x80\x03\x8c\x00\x03\x00S^k\xdb' //not actual value
```

Based on what I have read on the net, there is a `conn.add_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_BINARY, hexToString)` but its not working, the 
pyodbc version is at 4.0.18

```
import pyodbc

def hexToString(binaryString):
    try:
      hashString = ["{0:0>2}".format(hex(b)[2:],upper()) for b in binaryString]
      return '0x' + "".join(hashString)
    except:
      return binaryString

query = """ select * from myDb.TestDb """

conn_str = (
      r'Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
      r'Server=yourserver\test;'
      r'Database=test;'
      r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
      r'CHARSET=UTF8;'
    )


cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cnxn.add_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_BINARY, hexToString)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

try:
    cursor.execute(query)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
except MySQLdb.error as err:
    print(err)
else:
    while row is not None:
        print(row)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: What is the T-SQL column type that holds your binary data? BINARY ? VARBINARY ? something else ?

Comment: its binary(8), null

Comment: What happens when you run [this code](https://pastebin.com/FNNh7RhY) with no output converter function? I get `b'\xa0\x90\x80\xbd\x11\`\xab\x16'`

Comment: yes, its like that.

Comment: Okay, so your pyodbc connection is working properly. Are you confused by the fact that Python is showing you an actual binary value (`b'\xa0\x90...'`) instead of a string representation of that value (`'0xA090...'`)?

Comment: yes I am confused. What I need to display is the actual representation of that value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output converter function is failing because you are trying to call the `upper` string function with `,upper()` instead of `.upper()`. However, since you are doing the conversion for display purposes you really shouldn't be converting the returned value immediately via an output converter function, you should be formatting it just before you `print` it or pass it to a routine that will display it.

```python
crsr.execute("CREATE TABLE #tmp (id INT PRIMARY KEY, foo BINARY(8) NULL)")
crsr.execute("INSERT INTO #tmp (id, foo) VALUES (1, 0xA09080BD1160AB16)")
crsr.execute("SELECT foo FROM #tmp WHERE id=1")
binary_value = crsr.fetchval()  # b'\xa0\x90\x80\xbd\x11`\xab\x16'

# format for printing
print('0x' + binascii.hexlify(binary_value).decode().upper())
# prints:
# 0xA09080BD1160AB16
```

Comment: thank you very much, I actually copied this somewhere looks like he also missed this part